# Global Variable in Python, Javascript and C++

Tags: javascript, python, scope, global

I have a quick question regarding variable scopes, I have been previously working with c++, then I came to work with js and python recently and I've noticed something regarding how variables can be used inside functions.

in C++ in order to use/modify a global variable I need to pass if first as an argument, either for printing or changing it's value.

```
int increment(int);
int value = 0;

int main() {
    cout << increment(value) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int increment(int value) {
    value += 1; 
    return value;
}
```

and if I happened to define increment parameter-less/argument-less (assuming that it's going to use the global varieble "value"), i.e.

```
int increment() {
    value += 1; 
    return value;
}
```

and hence call the function with out passing any arguments `cout << increment() << endl;` , it will give an undefined variable, because the variable being locally used wasn't being introduced (passed) to the function scope, which I totally understand and seems much logical to me.

But in js and python **using a global variable without passing it to the function in the definition first is completely viable** :

```
// Javascript : access and reassignment are viable
var total = 0

function call(){
  total++ ;
  return total ;
}

console.log(call()) // 1
```

```
# Python : only access is viable 

value  = 0 

def inc():
    return "The value is {}".format(value)

print(inc()) # The value is 0
```

I'm just wondering why is it fine with python to allow functions to only access global variables (without even passing them to these functions beforehand) and not to reassign them as well, and where are these global variables and functions' definitions located in memory ?

Comment: Scope rules differ depending of language.

Comment: "* it will give an undefined variable"*. Work as expected [here](https://ideone.com/Qd0Yja).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy you are using a name variable that wasn't defined in your c++ code, i'm talkin about `value +=1` inside of your increment function, instead of that it should be

```
void increment(){
    num +=1 ;
}
```

The `void increment()` is because you don't need to return a value because you are modifying a global variable.

Also, when you compile a c++ program the compiler assign a specific zone for your code and your data, look at this [image](https://www.ele.uva.es/~jesus/hardware_empotrado/Compiler.pdf) and at [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

Comment: yes your're right, I edited it. my bad.

Comment: Don't worry mate, we are here to help, also js and python are programs that don't need to be compiled to work, they are **interpreted** so i can't help you to answer your question about where are the variables and functions in memory sorry

Comment: Thank you that was actually helpful ! , I didn't know that global variables could be used without being passed inside functions like that, and that's my bad too :)